Transform Java LocalDate in ThreeTen Library LocalDate
Im working with this library : implementation("com.github.thellmund.Android-Week-View:core:5.2.4")
In my calendar adapter im using this method :
  override fun onRangeChanged(firstVisibleDate: LocalDate, lastVisibleDate: LocalDate) {
        onRangeChange(firstVisibleDate)
    }

the parameter firstVisibleDate is a Java LocalDate object but i want to transform this localDate into ThreeTen LocalDate to work with versions < 26
Is there anyway to transform Java LocalDate to ThreeTen LocalDate?. Im working with current min api 23.

You can use Java LocalDate on API 23 with Java 8+ API desugaring support:
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3")
}

And if you still need to convert it to ThreeTen LocalDate, you can use one of the factory methods:
val threeTenDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(firstVisibleDate.toEpochDay())

